# Try/catch not working with android expression parser exp4j

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I am using the following bit of code to parse a string equation into a resulting double (based on some input values of doubles x, y and z and an equation input.). The program works fine when I run it as a java program in eclipse, however it hangs when I run it with in an android app (the app becomes unresponsive). In my app, I'm getting the string equation from a textbox and displaying the result number. Can anybody tell me why the following code doesn't work in android? My guess is that it has to do with the try-catch, but I can't figure out why. I'm using the exp4j jar.

Thanks very much!

```
public class ParseEquation {

    public double totalValue = 0;

    public ParseEquation(String inputEquation, double x, double y,double z) 
    {   
        //String inputEquation = "-4.14*x*x - 5/2 - y^2";
        Calculable calc = null;
        try {
            calc = new ExpressionBuilder(inputEquation)
                .withVariable("x", x)
                .withVariable("y", y)
                .withVariable("z", z)
                .build();
        } catch (UnknownFunctionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnparsableExpressionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        totalValue=calc.calculate();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you define *"it fails when I run it with in an android app"* and *"doesn't work"*? Does the app crash? Is there an exception logged in Logcat?

Comment: Log cat has text: "10-20 10:00:03.501: D/dalvikvm(7043): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8191K, 23% free 51270K/66396K, paused 26ms, total 26ms". Not sure if this is helpful. By fails I mean my android app becomes unresponsive and activity just stops; I can't press any more buttons or do anything.

Comment: Right, that means some long-running operation is blocking the main/ui thread (an ANR - Android Not Responding). Generally, Android will output thread state information into a file called `traces.txt` - have a look at it for clues. Alternatively, go over your code to identify potentially long-running, blocking operations. You'll have to offload this into a background/worker thread in order for the ui to remain responsive.

Comment: I'm not sure what's blocking the main thread. When I use a parser I wrote myself, everything works fine, in eclipse and in the android app. I compared the efficiency of the exp4j parser with my own parser and exp4j is a bit faster than my parser. Knowing this, nothing really should be using up resources to make the app unresponsive. therefore I am confused.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger before the ANR occurs, and once it kicks in, pause all running threads? That way you should be able to get an idea of what the main thread is busy with.

Answer (score 0):

Try use method of Log class, with 3 parameters.

```
public class ParseEquation {

    public double totalValue = 0;

    public ParseEquation(String inputEquation, double x, double y,double z) 
    {   
        //String inputEquation = "-4.14*x*x - 5/2 - y^2";
        Calculable calc = null;
        try {
            calc = new ExpressionBuilder(inputEquation)
                .withVariable("x", x)
                .withVariable("y", y)
                .withVariable("z", z)
                .build();
        } catch (UnknownFunctionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "catch block1", e);
        } catch (UnparsableExpressionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "catch block2", e);
        }

        totalValue=calc.calculate();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Still unresponsive. Something seems to be taking up  a lot of memory but I can't figure out what. It works fine and efficiently in eclipse.